# I am getting TesseractError: (2, 'Usage: pytesseract [-l lang] input_file') error while converting image to text in google colab

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr

**below is my code**

```
im=Image.open("/root/ppm_to_jpg/6e196d3b-adec-45ab-b036-5833f96f1bc0-2.jpg")
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/local/bin/pytesseract'
text=pytesseract.image_to_string(im,lang="eng")
print (text)
```

**I am getting erro as TesseractError: (2, 'Usage: pytesseract [-l lang] input_file') even i have set up the pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/local/bin/pytesseract**

**can anyone please suggest me what should i do**

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

`!sudo apt install tesseract-ocr`

The above installs the required dependencies for pytesseract. This is very important, especially the ! without which you cannot install directly to the underlying operating system.

`!pip install pytesseract`

This installs the Python binding.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The error messages in the question suggest that pytesseract is alreaddy installed.

Comment: `run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout) 232 with timeout_manager(proc, timeout) as error_string: 233 if proc.returncode: --> 234 raise TesseractError(proc.returncode, get_errors(error_string)) 235 236`

Comment: The pytesseract module is calling the fuction run_tesseract from the tesseract ocr engine, where it is obvious to get an error if the pytesseract and tesseract-ocr are not binded properly and shaing a common path and it is not necessary to explicitly declare a path `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/local/bin/pytesseract'` which throws the error. I also encountered the same problem and those two staments resolved it.